# Perl Array index to Hash value

Tags: arrays, perl, iteration, hashref

I'm new to Perl and I want to turn this:

```
$a = ["apple", "orange", "banana"];
```

Into this:

```
$b = { "apple" => 0, "orange" => 1, "banana" => 2 };
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this instead of iterating and assigning a counter manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I usually do that:

```
my $b = {};
@$b{@$a} = 0..$#$a;
```

Although it's not very idiomatic to use scalar references for everything; normally you would use an array variable to hold an array and a hash variable to hold a hash. That would make the array assignment look like this:

```
my @a = ("apple", "orange", "banana");
```

Or, more succinctly, like this:

```
my @a = qw(apple orange banana);
```

The hash setup then looks like this:

```
my %b;
@b{@a} = 0..$#a;
```

This takes advantage of the ability to assign to multiple keys in a hash at once:

```
my %h;
@h{'foo','bar'} = ('zoo','wicky');
```

That makes `$h{foo}` equal to `'zoo'` and `$h{bar}` equal to `'wicky'`.

By placing the array inside the curlies on the left, you get all the elements of that array in order as the hash keys to assign.  The range expression `0..$#a`, where `$#a` is the index of the last element of the array, expands to the list of integers 0,1,2,3,4,...,$#a on the right hand side of the assignment. So each array value is mapped to its index.